# How can I scrape a cgi python script from website?

Tags: python, selenium, cgi, web-scraping

I have just started learning about webscraping using selenium and mechanize with great results. I was wondering if it was at all possible to scrape a cgi python script from a site as well so I can replicate the sites functionality offline.

Here is an example script.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cgi-bin/hello.py

When I attempt to scrape this file I get the html output from the script instead of the script itself. Which is this:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Hello Word - First CGI Program</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Hello Word! This is my first CGI program</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

The details of the python script can be found here:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_cgi_programming.htm

If you can provide any insight I would be extremely grateful.

Thanks

Comment: What you are asking for is impossible. If you could access the scripts then it would be extremely insecure.

Comment: I was hoping that wasn't the case! Oh well, at least I know for sure.
Thanks

Comment: CGI-Scripts create HTML-Files on the fly, but the process and script itself will be executed on the server and is never exposed. See [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/cgi.html)

Answer (score 1):

Each site consists of two parts: the back-end and front-end.

"Back-end" means on the server side, usually PHP, Python, ASP or JSP languages.

"Front-end" means client side: HTML, JavaScript and CSS.

You, as a surfer view only the front-end, and this is what you scrape. You have no access to the back end.